# No response from KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I'm trying to make an easy Java program, but I cannot get any inpute from it. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


class KeyIns extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

 public void KeyIns(){
     addKeyListener(this); //==> this is why .... 
 }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("1");
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("2");
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("2");
}

}

public class Hello {
public static void main(String[] args){

    KeyIns inkey = new KeyIns(); 
    inkey.setSize(368, 300);
    inkey.setLocation(250, 250);
    inkey.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: to emphasize @Mad - _don't_ use keyListeners!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are never invoking the method

```
 public void KeyIns(){
     addKeyListener(this); //==> this is why .... 
 }
```

Either invoke the method KeyIns() or remove the word void (so that it becomes constructor) like this

```
 public KeyIns(){
     addKeyListener(this); //==> this is why .... 
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

`KeyListener` will only respond if the component it is registered to is both focusable and has focus.

The other problem is `JFrame` contains a bunch of other components on top of it, including the root pane and content pane. Registering a `KeyListener` to the frame is probably never going to achieve anything

A better solution would be to use the [Key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

A lot will matter based on what it is you are trying to achieve